# What is difference between while loop and for loop when using autorelease

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, asihttprequest

In my app, I use ASIHTTPRequest to download many files, when I use a for loop, the memory stay an acceptable level. But when I use while loop to do so, the memory usable reduce fast. All I do in ARC project. Does anyone know what happen when use for loop or while loop?

Comment: paste code you are investigating

Comment: it is because I check md5 more offen in whie loop than in for loop. At beginning, I think they will autorelease.

Answer (score 1):

For loop is used for known no of iteration. While loop is used for unknown iteration

i Think when you are using for loop, no of loop are executing with in a limitation

in case of while loop coz of unknown iteration it execute so many time